# Graphing the sum and average; pandas

Tags: pandas

```
total_income = df.groupby('title_year')['gross'].sum()
average_income = df.groupby('title_year')['gross'].mean()

print(plt.semilogy(total_income,average_income))
```

So I wanted to plot the total and average income on the same graph showing two lines. And I want my x-axis to show the years from 1916-2016 and y-axis to show in Dollars. But my code isn't doing that. I need help on how to change up my code in order to get what I needed

[Here's my output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HINA5.png).

Comment: It will help if add a snippet of your input data.

Comment: @DavidJaimes its a csv file containg big data

Comment: @DavidJaimes https://snag.gy/VDsA8b.jpg Here's how the graphs look. Top one is the total_income and bottom is the average_income when I plot them individually. And the x-axis shows the years. But when I plot them both it doesn't the years

Comment: Use pandas to plot total and average as a function of time. `total_income.plot(label="Total")`

Comment: @DavidJaimes It must shows the sum for each year for the total income and average for each year for the  average income. Using the data from 'gross'

Comment: @DavidJaimes How can I use plt.semilogy() with that?

Comment: I don't know what your DataFrame looks like so I can't give you specific answers. Unless you want to plot a log other than log-base-10, stick with the updated answer.

Comment: @Davidjaimes is there a way to just use plt.semilogy()? The graph should look like a log

Comment: @DavidJaimes https://snag.gy/LOVn24.jpg This is the output. My data contains NaN, is that why the lines breaks and isnt connected?

Comment: Yes, if you have NaN values in your data you will end up with gaps.

Comment: @DavidJaimes is there a way to not include NaN values in the graph or it will still show those gap even without the NaN value?

Answer (score 0):

This is my data file named `data.csv`:

```
year,gross
2015,45
2015,47
2015,49
2016,76
2016,78
2016,87
2017,103
2017,115
2017,133
```

1.) This is all the code to get the log-normal plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
total_income = df.groupby('year')['gross'].sum()
average_income = df.groupby('year')['gross'].mean()

total_income.plot(label="Total Income")
average_income.plot(label="Average Income")

plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("log$_{10}$(Gross)")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

2.) This is how you use `plt.semilogy()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
total_income = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('year')['gross'].sum())
average_income = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('year')['gross'].mean())

plt.semilogy(total_income.index, total_income["gross"],
             label="Total Income")
plt.semilogy(average_income.index, average_income["gross"],
             label="Average Income")

plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("log$_{10}$(Gross)")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("plot.png")
```

1.) and 2.) methods produce the following same plot.

[image]